# Calcular números quebrados

Tags: javascript

Possuo este trecho, mas no console aparece 64, e não 64.9. De que forma eu consigo somar da forma correta?

```
var carga_adicional = parseFloat('25,00');
var carga_parceiro = parseFloat('39,90');
var adicionais = parseFloat(carga_adicional + carga_parceiro);
console.log(adicionais);
```

Comment: Você vai ter que fazer um `replace(',', '.')` antes do parse, pois virgulas não são reconhecidas como separadores decimais.

Comment: sua pergunta é javascript e não jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troque a virgula pelo ponto

```
var carga_adicional = parseFloat('25.00');
var carga_parceiro = parseFloat('39.90');
var adicionais = parseFloat(carga_adicional + carga_parceiro);
console.log(adicionais);
```

Answer (score 1):

Cálculos matemáticos em JavaScript somente com números no formato americano, ou seja, decimal separado por ponto.

> Se os valores são passados via campos de texto, `independente de serem digitados com vírgula ou ponto`,  pode usar dessa forma:

```js
$("#ca,#cp").focusout(function(){
   //recupera valores dos inputs
   carga_adicional = $("#ca").val();
   carga_parceiro = $("#cp").val();
          
   //troca virgulas por pontos
   cA = carga_adicional.replace(/\,/g,'.');
   cP = carga_parceiro.replace(/\,/g,'.');
          
   //verifica se valor é nulo, se for atribui valor 0
   (cP == "")?cP=0:cP;
   (cA == "")?cA=0:cA;

   adicionais = ( parseFloat(cA) + parseFloat(cP) );
   adicionais=adicionais.toFixed(2);

   //representado como um valor em texto       
   adicionais = adicionais.toString();
          
   //retorna valor com virgula
   adicionais = adicionais.replace(/\./g,',');

 console.log(adicionais);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <input id="ca">
   <input id="cp">
```